# Jquery - .on not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### SOLVED!

My mistake was missing the jQuery operator function:

```
         <script>
            $(function() { // <-- THIS LINE
                $('body').on('change', '#billing_country', function() {
                    console.log($('#billing_country').val());
                    $.post("/store/ajax_get_zones", {
                        country_id: $('#billing_country').val()
                    }, function(e) {
                        if (e)
                            $("#billing_state").html(e);
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Thanks for the second pair of eyes guys. (Thanks @Adil for the extremely quick response)

---

### Orrignal Question:

I have the following very simple code running on my site that just broke for no apparent reason. I sware I've done this 100 times and for some reason it's not working now?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wallter/S6DDq/)

It works without the containing `(function() { ... }` am I doing it wrong?

### HTML

```
<div class="validate_the_fields_below" id="new_billing_address" style="">
    <table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="first_name">First Name*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="billing_first_name" value="" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="last_name">Last Name*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="billing_last_name" value="" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="phone">Phone*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input type="tel" name="billing_phone" value="" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="email">Email*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input type="email" name="billing_email" value="" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="address1">Address 1*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="billing_address1" value="" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="address2">Address 2</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input class="ignore required" type="text" name="" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="city">City*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="billing_city" value="" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="country">Country*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input">
                    <select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="required">

                        ...

                        <option value="219">Uganda</option>
                        <option value="220">Ukraine</option>
                        <option value="221">United Arab Emirates</option>
                        <option value="222">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="223">United States</option>

                        ...

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="state">State*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input">
                    <select name="billing_state" id="billing_state" class="required">

                        ...

                        <option value="3666">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="3667">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="3668">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="3669">Texas</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="3670">Utah</option>

                        ...

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="zip">Zip*</label>
                </td><td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="billing_zip" value="" class="required"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" class="required">                   
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
        <script>
            (function() {
                $('body').on('change', '#billing_country', function() {
                    console.log($('#billing_country').val());
                    $.post("/store/ajax_get_zones", {
                        country_id: $('#billing_country').val()
                    }, function(e) {
                        if (e)
                            $("#billing_state").html(e);
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Give @Adil credit for answering the question.

Comment: @Walter remove the solution from your question and click the Checkmark next to Adil's answer.

Answer (score 7):

You missed `$` for the jQuery for [**document.ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(function() {           

       $('body').on('change', '#billing_country', function() {
            console.log($('#billing_country').val());
            $.post("/store/ajax_get_zones", {
                country_id: $('#billing_country').val()
            }, function(e) {
                if (e)
                    $("#billing_state").html(e);
            })
        });
 });
```

You can also use more descriptive for of document.ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function({
     //Your code here.
});
```

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't executing the IIFE.

```
        (function() {
            $('body').on('change', '#billing_country', function() {
                console.log($('#billing_country').val());
                $.post("/store/ajax_get_zones", {
                    country_id: $('#billing_country').val()
                }, function(e) {
                    if (e)
                        $("#billing_state").html(e);
                })
            });
        })(); // <--- note the ()
```

Comment: `$(function() { ... }` == `(function() { ... }();` ?

Comment: Not at all, but from the code contained within, either would work. One executes immediately, the other executes on dom ready. You probably intended to use `$(function` to wait for dom ready.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works - http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/S6DDq/1/

You need to use `$` like this-

```
$(function() {
```